# Why a false statement can imply anything?

Tags: logic

According to the truth table,
If $P$ is false,then $P->Q$ is true.

if pigs fly, then $1+1=3$. Why is this implication true? How do you **prove** it?

Comment: You don't prove it, it's a definition.

Comment: Who says pigs don't fly?

Comment: maybe look at [this](http://legacy.earlham.edu/~peters/courses/log/mat-imp.htm)

Comment: You are confusing _a priori_ false, such as $1\ne 1$, with _a posteriori_ false, such as "the capital of mexico is london".  Pigs not flying is not _a priori_ false unless you say it is, and you haven't.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_priori_and_a_posteriori

Comment: My professor always said: "If the moon consists of green cheese then I am the imperator of China. But the moon is not made of green chees. So I didn't claim anything.". Somehow this made it clear for me. Maybe it will help you aswell :)

Answer (score 9):

Suppose you say that "If it's raining, then the ground is wet."

Then someone responds: "But the ground is dry."

Your response would be:  "So what?  It's not raining, so my statement is still valid!"

Comment: I don't think many people are confused that false can imply false. So more importantly: false can also imply true, and the ground can be wet even if it didn't rain. Neighbors could have washed their car, for example. Your description could mislead people into thinking that "it's raining $\Leftrightarrow$ the ground is wet".

Answer (score 5):

We know "pigs can't fly" is true, and by the law of the excluded middle, only one of the statements of { "pigs can't fly" , "pigs can fly"} is true.

But if we now suppose "pigs can fly" is true, then two of the statements of { "pigs can't fly" , "pigs can fly"} are true. But we've already shown only one is true, hence $1=2$. Adding one to both sides gives $1+1=2+1=3$.

QED.

Comment: This really made my day. :)

Comment: But if "pigs can fly" is true, then wouldn't "pigs can't fly" be false?

Answer (score 2):

In the style of Bertrand Russell and the Pope:

Assume we have a set of pigs $S$.  Two can't fly and one can.  How many pigs are in set $S$?   Well $|S| = 2 + 1 = 3$.

Let's $S_F$ be the number of pigs in $S$ that can fly.  Let $S_{\lnot F}$ be the number of pigs in $S$ that can't fly.  Since pigs can't fly, $|S_F| = 0$.  And we are given that $S_{\lnot F} = 2$.  So $|S| = |S_F| + |S_{\lnot F}| = 0 + 2 = 1 + 1$.

So $3 = 1 + 1$.

Comment: How come || = 0 ? It should be 1 as we have assumed that one pig in S can fly. @DanielV

Comment: We also assumed that pigs can't fly.

Comment: Can we assume this ?

Comment: @AbhinavArya That's the whole point of the question, to assume something that is false.  (And for it to be false, you must also be assuming the opposite, so there are 2 assumptions.)

Answer (score -2):

It's a convention, so you can say eg. for all $x\in\mathbb R$ the following is true:

$$x\geq0\Longrightarrow x^2\geq0$$

This would be false if you didn't define it that way, because $-1<0$ even though $(-1)^2>0$.